# Error inserting custom class to map as value

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-pair

I'm having trouble understanding why this isn't working as I expect it to. It may be that I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but hey.

This code is part of the item randomization system in a game engine I'm writing.

```
// the chance a rarity will have a given number of affixes
std::unordered_map<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>> affixCountChances = {

std::pair<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>>(ItemRarities::Cracked,
{ ChanceSelector<int>(
    { ChancePair(int, 100, 0) }) }),

std::pair<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>>(ItemRarities::Normal,
{ ChanceSelector<int>(
    { ChancePair(int, 80, 0),
     ChancePair(int, 20, 1) }) }),

    // snip for conciseness (there are 3 more)
};
```

And this is the ChanceSelector class:

```
using Percentage = int;

#define ChancePair(T, p, v) std::pair<Percentage, T>(p, v)

template <class T>
class ChanceSelector
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<T, Percentage> _stuff;

public:
    ChanceSelector()
    {
    }

    ~ChanceSelector()
    {
        if (_stuff.size() > 0)
            _stuff.clear();
    }

    ChanceSelector(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Percentage, T>> list)
    {
        // snip for conciseness
    }

    T Choose()
    {
        // snip for conciseness
    }
};
```

The above code compiles fine but I have two questions:

1. I don't understand why using ChanceSelector in std::pair requires a default constructor. Explicitly, it looks like I'm calling the constructor with the initializer list.
2. When the applications runs, it crashes with: `Unhandled exception at 0x01762fec in (my
   executable): 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee.`

Number 2 goes away if I only have one item in that map or if I change the definition of affixCountChances to `std::unordered_map<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>*>` (and adjust the rest accordingly). The error dumps me at this code in `list`:

```
for (_Nodeptr _Pnext; _Pnode != this->_Myhead; _Pnode = _Pnext)
{
    _Pnext = this->_Nextnode(_Pnode); // <-- this line
    this->_Freenode(_Pnode);
}
```

Further inspection reveals the error happened in the destructor. `_stuff` is empty:

```
~ChanceSelector()
{
    if (_stuff.size() > 0)
    _stuff.clear();
}
```

It is legitly calling the destructor. Items are being removed from `_stuff` but I don't see why it would be calling the destructor. The crash happens after all items have been constructed and affixCountChances contains all items. I would assume that means it's destroying all the temporaries it created but I don't see why it would be creating temporaries.

Edit:

Constructor of ChanceSelector:

```
ChanceSelector(std::initializer_list<std::pair<Percentage, T>> list)
{
    int total = 0;
    int last = 100;
    for (auto& item : list)
    {
        last = item.first;
        total += item.first;
        _stuff[item.second] = total;
    }
    // total must equal 100 so that Choose always picks something
    assert(total == 100);
}
```

Comment: I have not read it all but it sounds very much like you have a wrong move or copy constructor. Also be careful with reserved identifiers such as _stuff.

Comment: I've snipped out irrelevant code to make it a lot smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. `std::pair` requires a default constructor, because you can do something like

   ```cpp
   std::pair<int, MyClass> myPair();
   ```

   which creates a copy of your class using the default constructor (The values of the pair are  actual values and not references):

   ```
   // MSVC implementation
   template<class _Ty1,class _Ty2>
   struct pair 
   {   // store a pair of values
   typedef pair<_Ty1, _Ty2> _Myt;
   typedef _Ty1 first_type;
   typedef _Ty2 second_type;

   pair()
   : first(), second() // Here your class gets default constructed
   {     // default construct
   }

   // .....
   _Ty1 first; // the first stored value
   _Ty2 second;    // the second stored value
   };
   ```

   The template of the pair gets fully implemented, so you need a default constructor event if you are not using the line above.

   One way to avoid this dependency is to use pointers in the `std::pair`, this then sets the default value of the second value of the pair to `nullptr`:

   ```cpp
   std::pair<int, MyClass*> myPair();
   ```
2. `0xFEEEFEEE` indicates that the storage, where your pointer itself was stored has already been deleted (e.g. working on a deleted class reference).
   This deletion seems to occur somewhere outside the code you have posted here.
   For more `Magic Numbers` see [Magic Numbers on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values)

Edit:

Additionally, the contents of the initializer list do not exist after the constructor call. You might have there a reference copied instead of the actual object, which then gets deleted. The msvc implementation of the `std::unordered_map` uses a `std::list` as base for storing items. I'm not able to give your more information about this with the given code.

[Initializer list and lifetime of its content](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Edit 2: I was able to reproduce the error with your given code, it was not the content of the initializer_list ctor.
The problem seems to be the lifetime of the objects inside the initializer list.

When I move the declaration of the pairs for the unordered map out of the initializer_list for the unordered map, everything works fine:

```
std::pair<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>> pair1( ItemRarities::Cracked,
    { ChanceSelector<int>(
    { ChancePair( int, 100, 0 ) } ) } );
std::pair<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>> pair2( ItemRarities::Normal,
    { ChanceSelector<int>(
    { ChancePair( int, 80, 0 ),
    ChancePair( int, 20, 1 ) } ) } );
std::unordered_map<ItemRarities, ChanceSelector<int>> chances = {
        pair1,
        pair2
    };
```

I'm not completely sure why this is a problem, but I think is comes from the `{}` in the initializer list, those objects might get deleted, when leaving the first `{}` and before entering the actual intializer_list for the unordered_map

Comment: Ok on number 1. On 2, hmm. None of the code I left out looks like it has anything to do with that. There's no code in any of this that deletes anything. I tried creating a move constructor and assignment operator (and it called them!) but that didn't help.

Comment: Added some notes about the initializer list

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughness. I've added the constructor of the template class.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the bug and added information, how I solved the bug

Comment: That's messed up. Sounds like a compiler bug but it's not surprising given I'm pretty sure you couldn't use initializer lists with maps until semi-recently with MSVC.